# Swift Combine publisher value and system API

Tags: swift, combine

Let's say I have a system delegate like this

```
    func addPass(_ controller: PassViewController, data: Data) -> PassRequest
```

and then in a delegate I want to call combine publisher `func getPass() -> AnyPublisher<PassRequest, Error>` to return me `PassRequest` object.

```
func addPass(_ controller: PassViewController, data: Data) -> PassRequest {
   viewModel.getPass()
     .sink { completion in
       // completion here
     }
     .receiveValue: { result in
        return result
    }.store(in: &disposable)
    return result
}
```

What would be the way to return `result` to the system API in this case?

Comment: There is no one "right" way to do it. You can pass a callback function, you could use a delegate system, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to answer. There are a lot of considerations not covered in the narrow glimpse you've given.  It's likely this is an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

`Combine` publishers, like the one returned by `getPass` are tools for handling values that are generated, or delivered, asynchronously.

The caller to `getPass` might get a value at some future point, or it may not. That caller can go on to do other work until a value is available.

The caller of `addPass` wants no other work to get done until the value is available.

If you want to synchronize the work of `addPass` and the asynchronous value generated by `getPass` then `addPass` needs to wait until `getPass` emits a value.

If `addPass` is waiting, what happens if `getPass` never emits a value? Does it wait forever? Should it wait for a little while, then give up? What if `getPass` generates an error instead of a value?

If `addPass` *is* going to block, waiting for a result, then you certainly don't want to call it from the main thread - blocking the main thread is a Bad Thing™.

You can make it so `addPass` can wait. One option is using synchronization locks (e.g. `NSLock`). Those are tricky to get right.

You could also restructure your code so that `addPass` is also an asynchronous function and returns a value in a callback.  You could make `addPass` an `async` function (using Swift async/await concurrency) and have it suspend until `getPass` finishes its work.

There is not a single way to solve your problem, and with so many options, and no more detail about your system, there is really no good way to answer your question.